# Removing multiple XML Nodes using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I'm trying to remove the 2 root nodes from the XML file and I can't seem to get it right. I tried to remove the first part but to no avail.

I'm expecting the file to be like this:

```
 [{                
    "PartNumber" : "000096",
    "Location" : "A000",
    "Description" : "TEST OF RAMIS",
    "UnitOfMeasure" : "EA",
    "PartType" : "1",
    "FixedLeadTime" : "1",
    "MaterialType" : "Filling & Mixing Eq"
},{

    "PartNumber" : "000096",
    "Location" : "A000",
    "Description" : "TEST OF RAMIS",
    "UnitOfMeasure" : "EA",
    "PartType" : "1",
    "FixedLeadTime" : "1",
    "MaterialType" : "Filling & Mixing Eq"
}]
```

But it's coming this:

```
 {        
    "ns1:ZZMRP_Parts" : { "Part" :[{

    "PartNumber" : "000096",
    "Location" : "A000",
    "Description" : "TEST OF RAMIS",
    "UnitOfMeasure" : "EA",
    "PartType" : "1",
    "FixedLeadTime" : "1",
    "MaterialType" : "Filling & Mixing Eq"
},{

    "PartNumber" : "000096",
    "Location" : "A000",
    "Description" : "TEST OF RAMIS",
    "UnitOfMeasure" : "EA",
    "PartType" : "1",
    "FixedLeadTime" : "1",
    "MaterialType" : "Filling & Mixing Eq"
}] }}
```

What I need is the portion `"ns1:ZZMRP_Parts" : { "Part" :[{` removed.

**From comments:** input sample

```
<ns1:DDMRP_Parts xmlns:ns1="urn:za.xxxxxxxx.com:supplychain:3rdp:transdata">
  <Part>
    <PartNumber>000096</PartNumber>
    <Location>A000</Location>
    <Description>TEST OF RAMIS</Description>
    <UnitOfMeasure>EA</UnitOfMeasure>
    <PartType>1</PartType>
    <FixedLeadTime>1</FixedLeadTime>
    <MaterialType>Filling &amp; Mixing Eq</MaterialType>
  </Part>
  <Part>
    <PartNumber>000096</PartNumber>
    <Location>A000</Location>
    <Description>TEST OF RAMIS</Description>
    <UnitOfMeasure>EA</UnitOfMeasure>
    <PartType>1</PartType>
    <FixedLeadTime>1</FixedLeadTime>
    <MaterialType>Filling &amp; Mixing Eq</MaterialType>
  </Part>
</ns1:DDMRP_Parts>
```

Comment: Can you share your input XML and the xslt you have tried so far ?

Comment: this comment field is too small for me to post the input xml

Comment: You can edit your question and add the input XML in question only.

Comment: You have shown us JSON files, not XML.

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56068118/i-need-to-reformat-a-xml-file-to-json-using-xslt-and-remove-the-header-tags-and/56068341#56068341

Answer (score 0):

XSLT 3 can process JSON and with XPath 3.1 you could easily select only the part that interests you of the more complex input JSON you have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:output method="json" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="json">
        <xsl:sequence select="parse-json(.)('ns1:ZZMRP_Parts')?Part"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Assumes an input like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<json><![CDATA[
{        
    "ns1:ZZMRP_Parts" : { "Part" :[{

    "PartNumber" : "000096",
    "Location" : "A000",
    "Description" : "TEST OF RAMIS",
    "UnitOfMeasure" : "EA",
    "PartType" : "1",
    "FixedLeadTime" : "1",
    "MaterialType" : "Filling & Mixing Eq"
},{

    "PartNumber" : "000096",
    "Location" : "A000",
    "Description" : "TEST OF RAMIS",
    "UnitOfMeasure" : "EA",
    "PartType" : "1",
    "FixedLeadTime" : "1",
    "MaterialType" : "Filling & Mixing Eq"
}] }}
]]></json>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFN1y9B

Comment: Hi martin, the result is actually how we would like to get it. but it wont be from Json but from XML.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns1:DDMRP_Parts xmlns:ns1="urn:za.xxxxxxxx.com:supplychain:3rdp:transdata">
   <Part>

Comment: <PartNumber>000096</PartNumber>
      <Location>A000</Location>
      <Description>TEST OF RAMIS</Description>
      <UnitOfMeasure>EA</UnitOfMeasure>
      <PartType>1</PartType>
      <FixedLeadTime>1</FixedLeadTime>
      <MaterialType>Filling &amp; Mixing Eq</MaterialType>
   </Part>
   <Part>
      <PartNumber>000096</PartNumber>
      <Location>A000</Location>
      <Description>TEST OF RAMIS</Description>
      <UnitOfMeasure>EA</UnitOfMeasure>
      <PartType>1</PartType>
      <FixedLeadTime>1</FixedLeadTime>

Comment: <MaterialType>Filling &amp; Mixing Eq</MaterialType>
   </Part>
</ns1:DDMRP_Parts>

Comment: I cant seem to send the XML i want to send through.. is there a way i can email it to you?\

Comment: Well, you can edit your question https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56056344/edit and then insert all relevant details like a minimal but complete and representative XML, your current XSLT and the XSLT processor you use and then I am sure someone can help fix the XSLT. But don't try to stuff snippets into comments, edit your question and mark them up properly as code samples.