# Encapsulate XML into JSON list

Tags: json, xslt, sap-pi, sap-xi

I need to convert an XML source to a specified JSON format.  To do this I need to remove header nodes, retain the array body and encapsulate in square brackets `[ ]`.  I have converted the body but I am having trouble removing the header nodes and inserting the encapsulating square brackets `[ ]`.

This is the XML format I receive:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns1:DDMRP_Parts xmlns:ns1="urn:za.sabmiller.com:supplychain:3rdp:transdata">
   <Part>
      <PartNumber>000096</PartNumber>
      <Location>A000</Location>
      <Description>TEST OF RAMIS</Description>
      <UnitOfMeasure>EA</UnitOfMeasure>
      <PartType>1</PartType>
      <FixedLeadTime>1</FixedLeadTime>
      <MaterialType>Filling &amp; Mixing Eq</MaterialType>
   </Part>
   <Part>
      <PartNumber>000096</PartNumber>
      <Location>A000</Location>
      <Description>TEST OF RAMIS</Description>
      <UnitOfMeasure>EA</UnitOfMeasure>
      <PartType>1</PartType>
      <FixedLeadTime>1</FixedLeadTime>
      <MaterialType>Filling &amp; Mixing Eq</MaterialType>
   </Part>
</ns1:DDMRP_Parts>
```

I have tried using the adapter provided on SAP PI to do the conversion but this does not cater for a full array body.  I have tried to reformat using XSLT but I am not coming right with removing the outer nodes and encapsulating with square brackets `[ ]`.

This is my XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
       <xsl:output method="text"/>
       <xsl:template match="/">{
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>}
    </xsl:template>
       <!-- Object or Element Property-->
       <xsl:template match="*">
        "<xsl:value-of select="name()"/>" : <xsl:call-template name="Properties"/>
       </xsl:template>
       <!-- Array Element -->
       <xsl:template match="*" mode="ArrayElement">
              <xsl:call-template name="Properties"/>
       </xsl:template>
       <!-- Object Properties -->
       <xsl:template name="Properties">
              <xsl:variable name="childName" select="name(*[1])"/>
              <xsl:choose>
                     <xsl:when test="not(*|@*)">"<xsl:value-of select="."/>"</xsl:when>
                     <xsl:when test="count(*[name()=$childName]) > 1">{ "<xsl:value-of select="$childName"/>" :[<xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="ArrayElement"/>] }</xsl:when>
                     <xsl:otherwise>{
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                           <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    }</xsl:otherwise>
              </xsl:choose>
              <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*">,</xsl:if>
       </xsl:template>
       <!-- Attribute Property -->
       <xsl:template match="@*">"<xsl:value-of select="name()"/>" : "<xsl:value-of select="."/>",
    </xsl:template>
```

This is what I am currently producing:

```
{
        
        "ns1:DDMRP_Parts" : { "Part" :[{
                
        "PartNumber" : "000096",
        "Location" : "A000",
        "Description" : "TEST OF RAMIS",
        "UnitOfMeasure" : "EA",
        "PartType" : "1",
        "FixedLeadTime" : "1",
        "MaterialType" : "Filling & Mixing Eq"
    },{
                
        "PartNumber" : "000096",
        "Location" : "A000",
        "Description" : "TEST OF RAMIS",
        "UnitOfMeasure" : "EA",
        "PartType" : "1",
        "FixedLeadTime" : "1",
        "MaterialType" : "Filling & Mixing Eq"
    }] }}
```

This is what I need to output:

```
[{
                
        "PartNumber" : "000096",
        "Location" : "A000",
        "Description" : "TEST OF RAMIS",
        "UnitOfMeasure" : "EA",
        "PartType" : "1",
        "FixedLeadTime" : "1",
        "MaterialType" : "Filling & Mixing Eq"
    },{
                
        "PartNumber" : "000096",
        "Location" : "A000",
        "Description" : "TEST OF RAMIS",
        "UnitOfMeasure" : "EA",
        "PartType" : "1",
        "FixedLeadTime" : "1",
        "MaterialType" : "Filling & Mixing Eq"
    }]
```

Comment: Could you indent the XSLT properly, please?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <!-- array -->
    <xsl:text>[&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;]</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <!-- object -->
    <xsl:text>&#9;{&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="data"/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;&#9;}</xsl:text>
    <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
        <xsl:text>,&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="data">
    <!--  name/value pair -->
    <xsl:text>&#9;&#9;"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
    <xsl:text>" : "</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
        <xsl:text>,&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

P.S. The whitespace characters are optional and can be removed without affecting the validity of the JSON result.